# Flutter Error - 'package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart': Failed assertion: line 50 pos 15: 'image != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I get an error like this in the code I wrote today. Can you help me?

```
'package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart': Failed assertion: line 50 pos 15: 'image != null': is not true.
```

I am doing a weather application. I want the background photo to change according to the weather. But whatever I do, I couldn't get through this problem. I couldn't see any error similar to this error I received. Deadline time of my project is very close.

**MY CODE IS HERE:
*(If you want, I can add imported libraries.)***

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:uygulama1/Weather.dart';
import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherItem.dart';
import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherData.dart';
import 'package:uygulama1/ForecastData.dart';

//PROJECT'S ROOT
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "WeatherApp",
    home: MyApp(),
    
  ));
}

//PROJECTS MAIN CLASS
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
  
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  WeatherData weatherData;
  ForecastData forecastData;
  Location _location = new Location();
  String error;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadWeather();
  }


  Future<LocationData> getLocationData() async {
    return await _location.getLocation();
  }

// HERE IS PROBLEM
  final Map<String, AssetImage> images = {
    "rain": AssetImage("assets/images/rain.jpg"),
    "clear": AssetImage("assets/images/clear.jpg"),
    "thunderstorm": AssetImage("assets/images/thunderstorm.jpg"),
    "drizzle": AssetImage("assets/images/drizzle.jpg"),
    "snow": AssetImage("assets/images/snow.jpg"),
    "clouds": AssetImage("assets/images/clouds.jpg"),
  };
  

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Weather App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Weather App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
            //BACKGROUND IMAGE


//HERE IS PROBLEM
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                    image: weatherData == null
                        ? images["clear"]
                        : images[weatherData.name],
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
            //END

            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: weatherData != null
                        ? Weather(weather: weatherData)
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: isLoading
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 2.0,
                            valueColor:
                                new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.black),
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                            tooltip: 'Refresh',
                            onPressed: loadWeather,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: forecastData != null
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: forecastData.list.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => WeatherItem(
                              weather: forecastData.list.elementAt(index)))
                      : Container(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]))),
    );
  }

  loadWeather() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
      
    });

    LocationData location;
    try {
      location = await getLocationData();

      error = null;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = 'Permission denied';
      } else if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
        error =
            'Permission denied - please ask the user to enable it from the app settings';
      }

      location = null;
    }

    if (location != null) {
      final lat = location.latitude;
      final lon = location.longitude;

      final weatherResponse = await http.get(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=d89de3f0b2dedfe4f923f1e7f709953a&lat=${lat.toString()}&lon=${lon.toString()}');
      final forecastResponse = await http.get(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?APPID=d89de3f0b2dedfe4f923f1e7f709953a&lat=${lat.toString()}&lon=${lon.toString()}');

      if (weatherResponse.statusCode == 200 &&
          forecastResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        return setState(() {
          weatherData =
              new WeatherData.fromJson(jsonDecode(weatherResponse.body));
          forecastData =
              new ForecastData.fromJson(jsonDecode(forecastResponse.body));
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

**HERE IS MY WEATHERDATA CLASS:**

```
class WeatherData {
  final DateTime date;
  final String name;
  final double temp;
  final String main;
  final String icon;

  WeatherData({this.date, this.name, this.temp, this.main, this.icon});

  factory WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return WeatherData(
      date: new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(json['dt'] * 1000,
          isUtc: false),
      name: json['name'],
      temp: json['main']['temp'].toDouble(),
      main: json['weather'][0]['main'],
      icon: json['weather'][0]['icon'],
    );
  }
}
```

**WeatherItem Class:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherData.dart';

class WeatherItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final WeatherData weather;

  WeatherItem({Key key, @required this.weather}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var temperature = (weather.temp - 273.15).round();
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(weather.name, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            Text(weather.main,
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24.0)),
            Text('${temperature.toString()}°C',
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            Image.network(
                'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weather.icon}.png'),
            Text(new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(weather.date),
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            Text(new DateFormat.Hm().format(weather.date),
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Weather.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherData.dart';

class Weather extends StatelessWidget {
  final WeatherData weather;

  Weather({Key key, @required this.weather}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var temperature = (weather.temp - 273.15).round();
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(weather.name, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        Text("\n" + weather.main,
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 32.0)),
        Text("Temp: " + '${temperature.toString()}°C',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        Image.network('https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weather.icon}.png'),
        Text("Date: " + new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(weather.date),
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        Text("Hour: " + new DateFormat.Hm().format(weather.date),
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**ForecastData.dart:**

```
import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherData.dart';

class ForecastData {
  final List list;

  ForecastData({this.list});

  factory ForecastData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List list = new List();

    for (dynamic e in json['list']) {
      WeatherData w = new WeatherData(
          date: new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e['dt'] * 1000,
              isUtc: false),
          name: json['city']['name'],
          temp: e['main']['temp'].toDouble(),
          main: e['weather'][0]['main'],
          icon: e['weather'][0]['icon']);
      list.add(w);
    }

    return ForecastData(
      list: list,
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml file:**

```
name: uygulama1
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.11.3+16
  intl: ^0.15.6
  location: ^3.0.0
  flutter_map: ^0.10.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/

  uses-material-design: true
```

**and here is my GitHub link:** https://github.com/mahmutcankurt1/FlutterWeatherApp

Comment: Please check your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Everything looks fine in 'pubspec.yaml' file

Comment: and please don't delete your comments, i'm beginner at codding. :)

Comment: Oh.. okay.. I'll try to reproduce the error using your code.. I'll revert in sometime, right now windows is doing it's thing (update) :(

Comment: ok, i'm waiting you, thanks..

Comment: Oh..no that's not the case.. actually i asked to show me your api call..bt it was already there (..i didn't scrolled down..my bad.)..so..i thought i might be looking like a fool

Comment: Oh, hahaha :D. Don't mention it :)

Comment: Hey..dnt call loadweather from initState..make geLoadweather() get triggered when a button is clicked.

Comment: There is no problem there, the source of the error code is not there. And everything you say I tried has started to fail, I think I shouldn't.

Comment: Umm..give it a shot

Comment: nope **it's not work**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this, it WORKS!!

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:uygulama1/Weather.dart';
import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherItem.dart';
import 'package:uygulama1/WeatherData.dart';
import 'package:uygulama1/ForecastData.dart';

//PROJECT'S ROOT
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "WeatherApp",
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

//PROJECTS MAIN CLASS
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  WeatherData weatherData;
  ForecastData forecastData;
  Location _location = new Location();
  String error;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    triggerLoadFunction();
  }

  Future<LocationData> getLocationData() async {
    return await _location.getLocation();
  }

  bool isweatherDataLoaded = false;
  triggerLoadFunction() async {
    await loadWeather();
  }



// HERE IS PROBLEM
  final Map<String, AssetImage> images = {
    "rain": AssetImage("assets/images/rain.jpg"),
    "clear": AssetImage("assets/images/clear.jpg"),
"thunderstorm": AssetImage("assets/images/thunderstorm.jpg"),
    "drizzle": AssetImage("assets/images/drizzle.jpg"),
    "snow": AssetImage("assets/images/snow.jpg"),
    "clouds": AssetImage("assets/images/clouds.jpg"),
  };

AssetImage HandleError(){

if(images.containsKey(weatherdata.name){

return images[weatherdata.name];

}else {

return images["a default image when the exact weather image is not available."];

}
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Weather App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Weather App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            //BACKGROUND IMAGE
            Container(
              height: 90.0,
              width: 120.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: isweatherDataLoaded //this
                      ? HandleError()
                      : images["clear"],
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),


            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: weatherData != null
                        ? Weather(weather: weatherData)
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: isLoading
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 2.0,
                            valueColor:
                                new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.black),
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                            tooltip: 'Refresh',
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await loadWeather();
                            },
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: forecastData != null
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: forecastData.list.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => WeatherItem(
                              weather: forecastData.list.elementAt(index)))
                      : Container(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]))),
    );
  }

  loadWeather() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;

      isweatherDataLoaded = false;
    });

    LocationData location;
    try {
      location = await getLocationData();

      error = null;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = 'Permission denied';
      } else if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
        error =
            'Permission denied - please ask the user to enable it from the app settings';
      }

      location = null;
    }

    if (location != null) {
      final lat = location.latitude;
      final lon = location.longitude;

      final weatherResponse = await http.get(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=d89de3f0b2dedfe4f923f1e7f709953a&lat=${lat.toString()}&lon=${lon.toString()}');
      final forecastResponse = await http.get(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?APPID=d89de3f0b2dedfe4f923f1e7f709953a&lat=${lat.toString()}&lon=${lon.toString()}');

      if (weatherResponse.statusCode == 200 &&
          forecastResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        return setState(() {
          weatherData =
              new WeatherData.fromJson(jsonDecode(weatherResponse.body));

          isweatherDataLoaded = true;
          forecastData =
              new ForecastData.fromJson(jsonDecode(forecastResponse.body));
          isLoading = false;
          isweatherDataLoaded = true;
        });
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;

      isweatherDataLoaded = true;
    });
  }
}
```

So the problem was exactly what I said earlier, you called it in initState, so when the app state was created, it had no data from the WeatherData class, hence the app crashed.

Now, what i did is, i made use of a boolean variable isweatherDataLoaded to check if the weather data was loaded, and showing the image accordingly, i also gave a fixed height and width to the container for it to show properly.

Lemme know if it works for you.

Comment: At first I was able to see some of the image, but suddenly it gave the same error. What do you think I should do?

Comment: I think there is a small mistake, but I cannot see where the error is.

Comment: WeatherData must always return a string like "rain", "thunderstorm"..and all thise whim you specified in the images map..if it doesn't matches,it will throw the same error. If you want to check on which string the error was thrown, try adding print(weatherdata.name) in the function, and see what's the name.

Comment: And if it's very uncertain, then make a function to handle that..make a function that returns an AssetImage..and inside that function..chek if isweatherloaded is true..if it is, then check if weatherData.name also returns a string which you have specified in the images map, if it does then return images[weatherData.name], if it doesn't, then return a default image.

Comment: Hey..i have edited my code, i have added a HandleError() function to handle the error. Did this help?

Comment: Hi, `containsKey` is not defined? It says: `Function expressions can't be named.
Try removing the name, or moving the function expression to a function declaration statement.`

Comment: glad to hear that :). Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you so much, happy codding! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you copied your code from any other source it is recommended to do

```
Flutter clean and Flutter run
```